# Putting Image On JLabel

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

Trying to get image to display on the label:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
class Calculator {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/res/test.jpg"));
  frame.add(label);
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

I have tried changing the following code:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/res/test.jpg"));
```

to :

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("res/test.jpg"));
```

Comment: try `JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/test.jpg")));`. `res` must be in src folder. And don't forget Rebuild Project

Comment: got this error know:

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object

Comment: Sorry, with static method use `Calculator.class` instead of `getClass` @theRealJake

Comment: It is working only if I put the image in the src folder. I cannot make a res folder inside src for some reason. Thank you for the help